# CakePHP / Postgres nextval()

Tags: cakephp

in CakePHP how would go about running this query? It's to get the next sequence value in a postgres DB.

```
"SELECT nextval('book_id_seq')"
```

I'm used to using a syntax like `$this->find('all')` but that wouldn't work afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of query you can do it with the query function

```
$model->query($query);
```

$query is `"SELECT nextval('book_id_seq')";`

some special queries have to be done like this... at most you may get last inserted id in mysql

hope this helps you :)